# How to fix bundler missing /usr/bin/ruby-mri (LoadError)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine

I am executing the following line to test the installation of redmine-3.3:

```
bundle exec ruby script/server webrick -e production
> /usr/bin/ruby-mri: No such file or directory -- script/server (LoadError)
```

Apparently, the executable `ruby-mri` is missing. Does anyone know how I can fix this? I am running Fedora24. Installed ruby with `dnf install rubygem-rails`.

I installed ruby with `dnf install ruby`, now the file is present, but the error message stays the same. So there is a file `/usr/bin/ruby-mri`, but the error message complaints the file is not present. ???

Comment: Per http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall#Step-9-Test-the-installation, run `bundle exec rails server webrick -e production` for redmine 3+.

Answer (score 0):

It is the wrong command. `script/server` is outdated. Use instead:

```
bundle exec rails server webrick -e production
```